# How to make Windows 10 Game Bar appear on game?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10

I made a game using SDL and OpenGL in C++, which is of course common for games. Windows 10 should be able to detect that it's a game and show the Game Bar when starting it, but it doesn't. What can I do to make Windows 10 detect it as a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows cannot "detect" that you are playing a game. There is literally no way for it to magically work that out. Heck, I can think of a number of kinds of programs that a *human* would have difficulty categorising as a game or not (such as Stack Overflow, which doesn't use OpenGL or SDL whatsoever!).

Load up the game bar with Win+G, and check "Yes, this is a game" so that Windows remembers for next time.

- http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8686-game-dvr-remember-game-undo-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Why does it automatically appear on most games I play?

Comment: @Omega: Because someone at Microsoft has already checked that box for you. The key, here, is "most".

Comment: It comes up for Everything.exe (a free third-party file indexing/searching tool) is there a way to report that to Microsoft to remove that from their DB? This seems to be an issue everyone with Windows 10 (using VoidTools Everything)  is experiencing.  I can disable it, but this seems like an issue that should be resolved from a higher level.

Comment: Also, what criteria does that "check box" at Microsoft use to determine if it's the game?  Is it looking at the exe filename?  Hash of the exe (prob bad if an update comes out) or specific files in the program files folder?  Publisher metadata on the exe?  Combination of these?

Comment: @AdamPlocher: Probably

Comment: @RichardD If you have a new question, please ask it as such rather than in the comments under some other question. Thanks