# The windows game menu won't open in my game

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making a game with OpenGL and C++, I found that when I press Windows G the game bar won't open. I have tried the game bar on other games and most of them work. I also tested if the game bar would open on another game I saw on YouTube in C++ and OpenGL, the game bar doesn't open. Both games I tried are fullscreen games that hide the cursor, my game uses the new position of the cursor to work out movement. I'm using the visual studio compiler (`nvcc`).

To clarify if there is any confusion I'm not meaning the game bar says **"this is a game"** I'm meaning the game bar doesn't appear at all. All that happens is the screen flashes twice but there is nothing on screen.

Comment: Why is this on hold? It's a question about windows game bar and OpenGL, not about "why is my code not working!".

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141584/how-to-make-windows-10-game-bar-appear-on-game

Comment: This sounds like something that could be reproduced with a minimal program.

Comment: Afaik, the gamebar is never and for no game shown in fullscreen mode. ([Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/game-bar-not-opening-in-windows-10/2ca4c7cd-89ca-47b2-8a5b-be8cc1eedcb3)). It's also explained in the Game bar troubleshooting guide including the flicker twice thing: [Link](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/social/troubleshoot-game-dvr-windows-10#howdo)